# New to Python and not getting how to pull the 'Item' (key,value) from the rooms dict into my code

Tags: python

I need help defining a function that will allow me to access a dictionary key for each room that I enter for a text-based game that I am developing. I have tried doing this in different ways, but am confused about how to make this work.

I have tried creating a global variable that I could use dict.get(), which isn't working, I have tried to create a local variable that would pull the value of the key,value pairs and unfortunately I am just not familiar enough with dictionaries to make this work I guess.

I am not sure how to make this work and I am, quite frankly, getting discouraged.

I am trying to get the player to go from room to room, see an item, and then get it appended to their inventory. This is the part that keeps giving me issues. It says that the variable item is not defined.

```
# Function to show instructions and welcome the player to the game.
def show_instructions():
    print("Welcome to the Saga of Light Text Adventure Game!")
    print("Collect 6 items to win the game, or be beaten by The Dark Elf Nebo.")
    print("Movement commands: North, South, East, West, or Exit to leave the Game.")
    print("Add to Inventory: Get 'Item'")


# Define player location and state current inventory
def player_location():
    print('-' * 20)
    print('You are in the {}'.format(location))
    print('Inventory: ', inventory)
    print('-' * 20)


def get_new_location(location, player_move):
    new_state = location
    if location in rooms:
        if player_move in rooms[location]:
            new_state = rooms[location][player_move]

    return new_state


def get_room_item(location):
    item = rooms['Item']
    return rooms[location][item]


def main_gameplay():
    # Dictionary linking rooms and items obtain in them.
    rooms = {
        'Main Hall': {'South': 'Bedroom', 'North': 'library', 'East': 'Kitchen', 'West': 
         'Music Room'},
        'Music room': {'East': 'Main Hall', 'Item': 'Music Box'},
        'Bedroom': {'North': 'Main Hall', 'East': 'Safe room', 'Item': 'Cloak of 
         Strength'},
        'Safe room': {'West': 'Bedroom', 'Item': 'Bow & Arrows'},
        'Dining Room': {'South': 'Kitchen', 'Item': 'The Dark Elf Nebo'},
        'Kitchen': {'West': 'Main Hall', 'North': 'Dining Room', 'Item': 'Energy 
         Drink'},
        'Study': {'West': 'Library', 'Item': 'Ring of Light'},
        'Library': {'East': 'Study', 'South': 'Main Hall', 'Item': 'Book'}
    }

    return rooms


rooms = main_gameplay()


# Call for the function to display instructions
show_instructions()
location = 'Main Hall'
player_move = ''
inventory = []

# gameplay loop for game
while len(inventory) < 6:
    player_location()
    # variables for the starting room and player moves and empty inventory list.
    direction = player_move
    player_move = input('Which location would you like to go?\n').lower()  # Ask player 
                       for location to go.
    location = get_new_location(location, player_move)
    if player_move == 'Exit':  # If Exit is selected, game over.
        rooms = 'Exit'
        print('Thank you for playing!')  # Thank you message for playing
    # using if/else statements and dict for rooms and telling players where they are.
    if 'Item' in rooms[get_room_item(location)]:
        if player_move == ('Get' + 'Item').lower():
            inventory = inventory.append('Item')
        if location in rooms:
            if location == 'Main Hall':
                print()
            elif location == 'Safe Room':
                print(rooms.get('Item'))
                print('You see a ' + 'Item')
                print()
            elif location == 'library':
                print(rooms.get('Item'))
                print('You see a ' + 'Item')
                print()
            elif location == 'Music room':
                print(rooms.get('Item'))
                print('You see a ' + 'Item')
                print()
            elif location == 'Dining room':
                print(rooms.get('Item'))
                print('You see a ' + 'Item')
                print()
            elif location == 'Kitchen':
                print(rooms.get('Item'))
                print('You see a ' + 'Item')
                print()
            elif location == 'Study':
                print(rooms.get('Item'))
                print('You see a ' + 'Item')
                print()
        if len(inventory) == 6:  # Print congratulatory message!
            print('Congratulations! You have collected all items and defeated the The 
                  Dark Elf Nebo!')
            exit(0)
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: In your own words, where you have the function starting `def get_room_item(location):`, what is the purpose of that? Does it work as expected? If it does, do you see how you could use that to solve the problem?

Comment: The purpose was to use that, but I am having trouble getting it to work. Maybe I am not calling it right in my main function? I have tried just calling the function, but that doesn't seem to work(or Im not doing it right I guess). Unfortuantely I am not understanding how to use I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a nested dictionary, so you first need to index by the room, then you can get the item

```
print(rooms[location]['Item'])
```

In fact you already do this in your `get_room_item` function, so you can just use that

```
def get_room_item(rooms, location):
    return rooms[location]['Item']
```

If you just want to check that a room has an `'Item'` at all then just

```
if 'Item' in rooms[location]:
```

Comment: Thanks Cory! At least my function is ok then.  I guess what I am not understanding then is how to use that in the line ` if 'Item' in rooms[get_room_item(rooms, location)]:`  because it keeps giving KeyError 'Item'